# Google Cloud storage: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am facing a classic "Module not found error". However, I cannot solved my problem with the questions already posted.

I am trying to use the google.cloud API in order to download some data from a public Google repository to a local linux server.

Below are the instructions I used in a Jupyter server:

```
# Upgrading pip
!/usr/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

```
# Installing the Google cloud storage API
!pip3 install google
!pip3 install google-cloud-storage
```

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: google in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google) (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->google) (2.0.1)
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud-storage in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.30.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud-core<2.0dev,>=1.2.0 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-cloud-storage) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-resumable-media<2.0dev,>=0.6.0 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-cloud-storage) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.11.0 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-cloud-storage) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-cloud-core<2.0dev,>=1.2.0->google-cloud-storage) (1.22.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-crc32c<0.2dev,>=0.1.0; python_version >= "3.5" in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-resumable-media<2.0dev,>=0.6.0->google-cloud-storage) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-resumable-media<2.0dev,>=0.6.0->google-cloud-storage) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.11.0->google-cloud-storage) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.11.0->google-cloud-storage) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5" in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.11.0->google-cloud-storage) (4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.11.0->google-cloud-storage) (49.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core<2.0dev,>=1.2.0->google-cloud-storage) (2018.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core<2.0dev,>=1.2.0->google-cloud-storage) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.12.0 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core<2.0dev,>=1.2.0->google-cloud-storage) (3.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.6.0 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core<2.0dev,>=1.2.0->google-cloud-storage) (1.52.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-crc32c<0.2dev,>=0.1.0; python_version >= "3.5"->google-resumable-media<2.0dev,>=0.6.0->google-cloud-storage) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5"->google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.11.0->google-cloud-storage) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /home/antoine/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->google-crc32c<0.2dev,>=0.1.0; python_version >= "3.5"->google-resumable-media<2.0dev,>=0.6.0->google-cloud-storage) (2.20)
```

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-d626caf5a463> in <module>
----> 1 from google.cloud import storage
      2 
      3 
      4 def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
      5     """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when you have multiple versions of Python installed (with multiple Python 3.X versions), using `pip3` is not enough, as it does not necessarily install a package for the latest version of Python installed on your machine.
You can check what version of python your `pip3` is using by using the `pip3 --version` command.

If you plan to run a script with Python 3.8 and need to install a package for this specific version of Python, you can use:

`pip3.8 install PACKAGE` or
`python3.8 -m pip install PACKAGE`

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! pip3 is using python 3.8 but for some reason Jupiter is using Python 3.6.9, hence the mismatch!